# Parameters are passing but not retrieving when mobile.changepage in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, parameters

Hello I have a search field with search button and two drop-down list values when i click the search button i want to pass the parameter values using mobile.change method.I am using like following structure

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Client View</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('pagebeforeshow',function(){

    $("#searchbutton").on('click',function(){

   var searchvalue = $("[name='clientsearch']").val();
  var searchbyvalue = $("#select-choice-searchby").val();
  var statusvalue = $("#select-choice-status").val();

   $.mobile.changePage(
     'accountlist.html',
    { 
     //dataUrl : "accountlist.html?searchvalue="+searchvalue&"searchbyvalue="+searchbyvalue&"statusvalue="+statusvalue , 
    data : { 'searchvalue' : searchvalue,'searchbyvalue':searchbyvalue,'statusvalue':statusvalue }, 
    reloadPage : false, 
    changeHash : true 
    });
  });
});
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <!--Client Page-->

         <div data-role="page" id="client" data-add-back-btn="true" >
         <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="persistantFooter">
 <h1>Client View</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="searchbox">
     <input type="search" name="clientsearch" value="" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"/>
     <input type="button" value="Search" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" id="searchbutton"/>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain"  >
         <label for="select-choice-searchby"  class="select" data-inline="true" style = "width: 90px">Search By:</label>
         <select name="select-choice-searchby" id="select-choice-searchby" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" style = "float: right">
            <option value="account">Account</option>
            <option value="customhouseholds">Custom Households </option>
            <option value="roahouseholds">ROA Households</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"  >
        <label for="select-choice-status"  class="select" data-inline="true" style = "width: 90px">Status:</label>
         <select name="select-choice-status" id="select-choice-status" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" style = "float: right">
            <option value="open">Open</option>
            <option value="closed">Closed </option>
            <option value="all">All</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**page2.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Account view</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('pagebeforeshow',function(){
alert("hi");
//  var parameters = window.location.pathname.split("?")[1];
//alert(getUrlVars())
var searchvalue = getUrlVars()[0];
 var searchbyvalue = getUrlVars()[1];
 var statusvalue = getUrlVars()[2];
 alert(searchvalue);

function getUrlVars()
{
    var qName = [], hash;
    var qVal=[];
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        qName.push(hash[0]);
        qVal.push(hash[1]);
        qName[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return qVal;
    }
       });
     // JavaScript Document
    </script>
 </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="accountlist" data-add-back-btn="true" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h3>Account View</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    </div> <!--content-->
</div><!--page-->
    </body>
        </html>
```

in the page2.html we cannot access the parameter values and also the script function not execute how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I have considered single page concept, you can change you code accordingly:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Client View</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/js/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <!--Client Page-->

         <div data-role="page" id="client" data-add-back-btn="true" >
         <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="persistantFooter">
 <h1>Client View</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="searchbox">
     <input type="search" name="clientsearch" value="" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"/>
     <input type="button" value="Search" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-param1="" data-param2 ="" data-param3="" data-mini="true"  id="searchbutton"/>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain"  >
         <label for="select-choice-searchby"  class="select" data-inline="true" style = "width: 90px">Search By:</label>
         <select name="select-choice-searchby" id="select-choice-searchby" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" style = "float: right">
            <option value="account">Account</option>
            <option value="customhouseholds">Custom Households </option>
            <option value="roahouseholds">ROA Households</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"  >
        <label for="select-choice-status"  class="select" data-inline="true" style = "width: 90px">Status:</label>
         <select name="select-choice-status" id="select-choice-status" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" style = "float: right">
            <option value="open">Open</option>
            <option value="closed">Closed </option>
            <option value="all">All</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="accountlist" data-add-back-btn="true" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h3>Account View</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    </div> <!--content-->
</div><!--page-->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#client").on('pageshow',function(){

    $("#searchbutton").on('click',function(){

   var searchvalue = $("[name='clientsearch']").val();
  var searchbyvalue = $("#select-choice-searchby").val();
  var statusvalue = $("#select-choice-status").val();


  $("#searchbutton").data("param1", searchvalue);
  $("#searchbutton").data("param2", searchbyvalue);
  $("#searchbutton").data("param3", statusvalue);


   $.mobile.changePage(
     '#accountlist', {     
    reloadPage : false, 
    changeHash : true 
    });
  });
});

$("#accountlist").on('pageshow',function(){
    alert( $("#searchbutton").data("param1"));
    alert( $("#searchbutton").data("param2"));
    alert( $("#searchbutton").data("param3"));
});

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I want to implement the SEO(search engine optimization)concepts in my application.so I do only multiple page concept

Comment: if the above data-param concept doesn't work for you them might as well use wndow.sessionStorage and set and get items for next page.

Comment: in my above code of script is only working in inside of body but when i put the code into head  tag its not working..

Comment: in jquery mobile you should never put pageshow events in head section, it should always go in body below the page div's or in another js file after all scripts are loaded.